# SQL Server - Breadcrumb Type Effect

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a set of data such as the following:

```
ID, Description, ParentID
1,  Savoury, -1
2,  Cheese, 1
3,  Pastry, 1
4,  Quiche, 1
5,  Sweet, -1
6,  Chocolate, 5
...
```

What I'm looking to do is write a stored procedure which will produce a set of results similar to a breadcrumb link in a web browser. Something like the following would be ideal...

```
ID, BreadCrumb
1, Savoury
2, Savoury >> Cheese
3, Savoury >> Pastry
4, Savoury >> Quiche
5, Sweet
6, Sweet >> Chocolate
...
```

Items such as Cheese or Pastry wouldn't be listed as items on their own (like Sweet is). So far, I have the following code which works but it lists everything, regardless of whether it has a ParentID

```
With BreadCrumb AS 
(
SELECT CAST(a.Description AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Path, a.ID, a.ParentID
FROM FoodStuff a

UNION ALL

SELECT CAST(BreadCrumb.Path + ' >> ' + b.Description AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Path, b.ID, b.ParentID
FROM FoodStuff b
INNER JOIN BreadCrumb ON BreadCrumb.ID = b.ParentID

)

SELECT * FROM BreadCrumb
ORDER BY Path
```

I'd be grateful for a nudge in the right direction.

Thanks in advance,
Kev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a condition in the anchor portion of the recursive CTE in order to limit it to root items:

```
With BreadCrumb AS 
(
SELECT CAST(a.Description AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Path, a.ID, a.ParentID
FROM FoodStuff a
WHERE a.ParentID = -1 -- select roots only

UNION ALL

SELECT CAST(BreadCrumb.Path + ' >> ' + b.Description AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Path, b.ID, b.ParentID
FROM FoodStuff b
INNER JOIN BreadCrumb ON BreadCrumb.ID = b.ParentID
)
```

You don't need a similar condition in the recursive half of the CTE as the inner join should take care of it, since *presumably* you don't have any records with ID = -1.

As a best-practices aside, I'd recommend using NULL instead of -1 for foreign keys which are allowed not to have a value, such as ParentID.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4c84c/2), courtesy of @Conrad Frix.

Comment: That's just perfect. Thanks for your help!